# Updating data in UITableView is not smooth

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to display the already saved data in the `tableView`. At the same time, I am checking for new data by a web service. When I receive data from the network, my database gets updated with the new data. The `tableView` automatically gets updated.
But the update in `tableView` is not smooth. Please offer a suitable solution for `swift 4`.
Please watch this video which I have uploaded for the better explanation.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhSEykQcP5A&feature=youtu.be

This is my `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate implementation

```
extension CoreDataTableViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    let set = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)
    switch (type) {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertSections(set, with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(set, with: .fade)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch(type) {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .update:
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .move:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Show us `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate implementation

Comment: I have edited the question to show the NSFetchedResultsController delegate implementation. I am not calling reloadData() anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

Earlier, I was using `saveContext` only once (after the for loop), after all the `NSManagedObject` were generated. Now, I am using `saveContext` after generating each `NSManagedObject`. Below is the snippet of the code where I am creating the `NSManagedObject` and saving them.

```
                        for z in 0...(json.count - 1) {
                        let a = json[z]["PackageName"].stringValue
                        let b = json[z]["ExamGroupId"].stringValue
                        let c = json[z]["TestList"].stringValue
                        let d = json[z]["TestPackageId"].stringValue
                        _ = TestPackage(packageNameCD: a, examGroupIdCD: b, testListCD: c, testPackageIdCD: d, context: self.fetchedResultsControler.managedObjectContext)
                        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext() // now I am saving here itself and not after the loop.

                    }
                    // (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext() // earlier, I was saving here, after the for loop.
```

I have yet not fully understood it. But it does solve the problem. 
I will be very thankful to anyone who can explain it further.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.endUpdates()
```

Apple says:

> Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and
>   selection operations.

...

> You should not call reloadData() within the group; if you call this
>   method within the group, you must perform any animations yourself.